# Left Click not opening files/folders

Tags: desktop-environments

everyone, all of a sudden, my left click will not open a folder within the file explorer. I can still double to bring down the drop-down menu. I've done a little googling but have not been able to fix it. Can anyone help me out?

I am on version 16.04 and I use a touchpad, but the same problem occurs with a mouse as well.

Comment: can you please check whether mouse left click is working?

Comment: left click is working when i test it, it is set to primary button

Comment: I fixed the problem. The double-click speed was set so high that I couldn't tap that fast :-P